# How to create CIM provider

Tags: wsman, openwsman

1. Have any tutorial for implementing CIM provider for software update profile?
2. I want to know about vendor_namespaces in openwsman.conf file.
3. If we created a new profile, how to create schema, and where it is hold?.. 
   4 if we using existing profile, Need to create new schema?
4. Please describe me the steps for developing new CIM projects for(DSP1025,DSP1033,DSP1034,DSP1039,sotwareupdate). I want to develope a new CIM providers for this.. How it achieve it?
5. Sample soap request for this profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some useful links for implementing it.

I had using sblim development packages for implementing new provider. In opensman config file, we can specify the vendor names .

for referring sample provider are available,
http://sblim.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sblim/

Please see the sample provider,
https://github.com/georgooty/GK_SampleProvider